# Scheme (DrRacket) - Outputting an entire Structure

Tags: scheme, structure, racket

I'm fairly new to Scheme and I'm using DrRacket and I hope to get some much needed assistance.

I need to "combine" the four field values of my structure to make a single structure which you should be returning.

The four field values I am referring to are in the if statement of the code:

**((auction-itemnum anentry)(auction-name anentry)(auction-currbid anentry)(auction-status anentry))**

That of course does not work, as it won't let me run that.

This means my second if statement isn't going to work either, but if I can figure out the first one, then the second one will be clear.

The output I need is: (make-auction 50 "Bob" 100 "Open")

(at least for the second check-expect)

But figuring out the second check-expect will make the others work as well.

Here is my code:

```
(define-struct auction (itemnum name currbid status))

(define Auction1
  (make-auction 50 "Bob" 100 "Open"))

(define Auction2
  (make-auction 20 "Joe" 40 "Closed"))

;; Data Definition of an auction
;; An auction is a structure: (make-auction itemnum name currbid status)
;; interp. item number, name, current bid, and status, represented
;;         by a string

;; Signature: auctionbid: string number entry -> entry
;; Purpose: Consumes a bidder, a bid amount, and an auction entry
;;          then returns an entry
;; Tests:
(check-expect (auctionbid "Frank" 150 Auction1) (make-auction 50 "Frank" 150 "Open"))
(check-expect (auctionbid "Billy" 80 Auction1) (make-auction 50 "Bob" 100 "Open"))
(check-expect (auctionbid "Jenny" 50 Auction2) (make-auction 20 "Joe" 40 "Closed"))
;; Define:
(define (auctionbid aname bid anentry)
  (cond
    [(or (< bid (auction-currbid anentry)) (string=? "Closed" (auction-status anentry)))
     ((auction-itemnum anentry) (auction-name anentry)
      (auction-currbid anentry) (auction-status anentry))]
    [(> bid (auction-currbid anentry))
     ((auction-itemnum anentry)(aname)
      (bid)(auction-status anentry))]
     ))
```

Comment: Although I could post an answer, I think you're very close to figuring it out yourself. A hint: How do you make an instance of the `auction` structure? For example, how did you do so for the `Auction1` and `Auction2` variables? Could you do the same thing in the two places in your `cond` expression?

Comment: Perhaps I am just overthinking it because I still can't seem to figure this out. It makes me think that I should put '(make-auction (auction-itemnum anentry) (auction-name anentry) (auction-currbid anentry) (auction-status anentry))' in the if statement, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @BBladem83 Can you post the _actual_ code you tried that doesn't work? This problem is really easy. Hint: the second case should read `(make-auction (auction-itemnum anetry) aname bid (auction-status anentry))`, that is to say, `aname` and `bid` must not be surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young wow, alright. I figured it out. I feel really dumb haha. Thank you!

Comment: It is ok to answer your own question and to accept that answer. That makes it easier for someone else with the same question to Google it up later...or if they don't Google up the answer but ask it here instead for someone to quickly point that person to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason in the world why you'd ever want a copy of an immutable struct. Just return the struct itself if you're not changing anything. Otherwise, you need to construct a new struct using "make-auction":

```
(define (auctionbid aname bid anentry)
  (cond
    [(or (< bid (auction-currbid anentry))
         (string=? "Closed" (auction-status anentry)))
     anentry]
    [(> bid (auction-currbid anentry))
     (make-auction (auction-itemnum anentry)
                   aname bid 
                   (auction-status anentry))]))
```